# Sending filename to VS Code to build latex file

Tags: latex, visual-studio-code

I want to build tex file in VS Code. I have tasks.json like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
          {
            "label": "Run lualatex",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "command": "lualatex",
            "args": [
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%.tex"
            ]
        },
    ]
   }
```

While pressing Ctrl+Alt+B I get this message:
Executing task: lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error %DOC%.tex

I tried "%DOC%" and "*.tex", but nothing works. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Integrate with External Tools via Tasks - Variable substitution](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution)

> When authoring tasks configurations, it is useful to have a set of predefined common variables such as the active file (${file}) or workspace root folder (${workspaceFolder}). VS Code supports variable substitution inside strings in the tasks.json file and you can see a full list of predefined variables in the [Variables Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference).